# Pearson correlation in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, correlation

I'm trying to implement the calculation of correlation coefficient of people between two sets of data in php.
I'm just trying to do the porting python script that can be found at this url
http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1066-how-to-find-similar-users-with-python/

my implementation is the following:

```
class LB_Similarity_PearsonCorrelation implements LB_Similarity_Interface{
public function similarity($user1, $user2){

    $sharedItem = array();
    $pref1 = array();
    $pref2 = array();

    $result1 = $user1->fetchAllPreferences();
    $result2 = $user2->fetchAllPreferences();

    foreach($result1 as $pref){
        $pref1[$pref->item_id] = $pref->rate;
    }

    foreach($result2 as $pref){
        $pref2[$pref->item_id] = $pref->rate;
    }

    foreach ($pref1 as $item => $preferenza){
        if(key_exists($item,$pref2)){
            $sharedItem[$item] = 1;
        }
    }

    $n = count($sharedItem);
    if ($n == 0) return 0;

    $sum1 = 0;$sum2 = 0;$sumSq1 = 0;$sumSq2 = 0;$pSum = 0;

    foreach ($sharedItem as $item_id => $pre) {
        $sum1 += $pref1[$item_id];
        $sum2 += $pref2[$item_id];

        $sumSq1 += pow($pref1[$item_id],2);
        $sumSq2 += pow($pref2[$item_id],2);

        $pSum += $pref1[$item_id] * $pref2[$item_id];
    }

    $num = $pSum - (($sum1 * $sum2) / $n);
    $den = sqrt(($sumSq1 - pow($sum1,2)/$n) * ($sumSq2 - pow($sum2,2)/$n));
    if ($den == 0) return 0;
    return $num/$den;

}
}
```

clarification to better understand the code, the method fetchAllPreferences return back a set of objects that are actually the items, turns them into an array for ease of management

I'm not sure that this implementation is correct, in particular I have some doubts about the correctness of the calculation of the denominator.

any advice is welcome.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to write out this equation?

http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/2/2/d/22d8661430d51f01217a3426466aae8b.png

Comment: yes. I also use Excel to check the result and seem correct.
But i also want a double check.

Comment: is user1 and user2 X and Y, or are there lots of X and Ys (trig/calc has never been my strong suit, but figuring out how to slap a computer around to do math is something I enjoy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your algorithm looks mathematically correct but numerically unstable.  Finding the sum of squares explicitly is a recipe for disaster.  What if you have numbers like `array(10000000001, 10000000002, 10000000003)`?  A numerically stable one-pass algorithm for calculating the variance can be [found on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance), and the same principle can be applied to computing the covariance.

Easier yet, if you don't care much about speed, you could just use two passes.  Find the means in the first pass, then compute the variances and covariances using the textbook formula in the second pass.

Comment: My algorithm never treat this big numbers and the speed is not a critical point because this calculation is done offline. But i really enjoy your answer certainly go into the topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is my solution:

```
function php_correlation($x,$y){
    if(count($x)!==count($y)){return -1;}   
    $x=array_values($x);
    $y=array_values($y);    
    $xs=array_sum($x)/count($x);
    $ys=array_sum($y)/count($y);    
    $a=0;$bx=0;$by=0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($x);$i++){     
        $xr=$x[$i]-$xs;
        $yr=$y[$i]-$ys;     
        $a+=$xr*$yr;        
        $bx+=pow($xr,2);
        $by+=pow($yr,2);
    }   
    $b = sqrt($bx*$by);
    if($b==0) return 0;
    return $a/$b;
}
```

http://profprog.ru/korrelyaciya-na-php-php-simple-pearson-correlation/

Answer (score 1):

try my package here

http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/5854.html

Comment: You should put your code on github if you want anyone to use it.  The current site is terrible.