# what's wrong with my PHP pearson correlation coefficient code

Tags: php, algorithm, math, correlation

so I was trying to implement the Sample Pearson Correlation Coefficient in PHP:

(go to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient and search for "Alternative formulae for the sample Pearson correlation coefficient are also available" for the specific formula I was trying to implement)

```
   $sum = 0;
   $TF1 = 0;
   $TF2 = 0;
   $wSquare1 = 0;
   $wSquare2 = 0;
   $m = sizeof($sample);
   foreach($sample as $x){
      if(!isset($obj1[$x])){
         $obj1[$x]['count'] = 0;
      }
      if(!isset($obj2[$x])){
         $obj2[$x]['count'] = 0;
      }
      $sum += $obj1[$x]['count'] * $obj2[$x]['count'];
      $TF1 += $obj1[$x]['count'];
      $TF2 += $obj2[$x]['count'];
      $wSquare1 += $obj1[$x]['count']^2;
      $wSquare2 += $obj2[$x]['count']^2;
   }
   $numer = $sum * $m - $TF1 * $TF2;
   $denom_left = $m*$wSquare1 - $TF1^2;
   $denom_right = $m*$wSquare2 - $TF2^2;
   $denom = sqrt($denom_left) * sqrt($denom_right);
   $pears = $numer / $denom;
   return $pears;
```

but then sometimes my code would return a value that is greater than 1 while PCC is not supposed to exceed 1....

am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your code misses the example data and you should name with which of those it fails. Perhaps you should write a unit-test for that function first? Or is stackoverflow your unit-testing? :)

Comment: the example data is rather large to put in here...and I'm trying to see if my implementation of the mathematics is correct so that I can focus on figuring out the data rather than the mathematics

Comment: Well, make it available on github or alike and add unittests with the testdata. Then share the link.

Comment: just check the mathematics. don't worry about the data

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Pearson correlation in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408677/pearson-correlation-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven’t fully checked your math, but one thing that popped out to me was
`$TF1^2` and `$obj1[$x]['count']^2`. They’re using the [bitwise XOR operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

I believe you want `pow($TF1, 2)` and `pow($obj1[$x]['count'], 2)`

alternatively:
`$TF1 * $TF1` and `$obj1[$x]['count'] * $obj1[$x]['count']`

It’s a common mistake.

Also be aware of the disclaimer from the article:

> The above formula suggests a convenient single-pass algorithm for
>   calculating sample correlations, but, **depending on the numbers
>   involved, it can sometimes be *numerically unstable*.**

Comment: @yi_H: Good point! That _would_ avoid a function call. I guess it only matters if you're [micro-optimizing](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/01/micro-optimization-and-meatballs.html). :)

Comment: I tried to optimize it for *readability* it looks a bit better with simple expressions :)

Comment: @yi_H: touché :). In any case, now the OP is aware of the `pow()` function: lest we end up with `$TF1*$TF1*$TF1*$TF1*$TF1*$TF1`. :-)