# Retrieve All Data From One Table in Database into Array and Calculate it

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, recommendation-engine

Related to question from this [Pearson correlation in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408677/pearson-correlation-in-php?rq=1) , now I'm using that function too for calculate similarity between 2 users with pearson correlation. What I wanna ask is :

1. I have database name ta_db
2. And I want to retrieve data from table interest which have 9 attributes into array
3. After that I want to calculate it with pearson correlation function.

> public function similarity($user1, $user2) {
>
> ```
>     $sharedItem = array();
>     $pref1 = array();
>     $pref2 = array();
>
>     $result1 = $user1->fetchAllPreferences();
>     $result2 = $user2->fetchAllPreferences();
>
>     foreach($result1 as $pref){
>         $pref1[$pref->item_id] = $pref->rate;
>     }
>
>     foreach($result2 as $pref){
>         $pref2[$pref->item_id] = $pref->rate;
>     }
>
>     foreach ($pref1 as $item => $preferenza){
>         if(key_exists($item,$pref2)){
>             $sharedItem[$item] = 1;
>         }
>     }
>
>     $n = count($sharedItem);
>     if ($n == 0) return 0;
>
>     $sum1 = 0;$sum2 = 0;$sumSq1 = 0;$sumSq2 = 0;$pSum = 0;
>
>     foreach ($sharedItem as $item_id => $pre) {
>         $sum1 += $pref1[$item_id];
>         $sum2 += $pref2[$item_id];
>
>         $sumSq1 += pow($pref1[$item_id],2);
>         $sumSq2 += pow($pref2[$item_id],2);
>
>         $pSum += $pref1[$item_id] * $pref2[$item_id];
>     }
>
>     $num = $pSum - (($sum1 * $sum2) / $n);
>     $den = sqrt(($sumSq1 - pow($sum1,2)/$n) * ($sumSq2 - pow($sum2,2)/$n));
>     if ($den == 0) return 0;
>     return $num/$den;
>
> }
> ```

From my explanation above, could you please tell me how to retrieve the data into Array? Thank you in advance for your help and clear explanation.

Comment: it should be inside fetchAllPreferences function

Comment: @Undefined_variable so I have to make another function named "fetchAllPreferences" or like what? Can you give some example please? Thanks.

Comment: you are calling that function is it defined or not? If not your PHP script should fail

Comment: @Undefined_variable now I'm using one function to retrieve data one by one with function named getRating().